# Is onPause() called when user closes the app from recents

Tags: android, onpause, activity-lifecycle

I read a lot about activity lifecycle but I cannot find a simple answer. Let's assume someone is pressing *Switch apps* hardware button. When app is switched to a different app `onPause()` is guaranteed to be called. Also pressing *Back* (to close the app) or *Home* will invoke `onPause()`.

But here is the question. When I open app list where I can switch between apps will just the button click invoke `onPause()`? I mean is just clicking *Switch apps* invokes `onPause()`?

It's not clear to me and the documentation doesn't describe that case.

EDIT:
I was wrong saying that `onPause()` is not invoked after the button click only. I'm sorry.

Comment: @downvoter care to comment what was wrong with my answer ? that you downvoted immediately within milli seconds of my posting it.

Comment: @Sharpedge tell me about it. -_-

Comment: "onPause() will not be called until someone choses a different app from the list" This is false, atleast on my device onPause is called when the button is pressed to show the list of apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Activity page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), `onPause()` will be called. Any app that is in the foreground will call `onPause()` the moment the user pulls up the app list to start swiping away apps.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's assume someone is pressing Switch apps hardware button. `onPause()` will not be called until someone choses a different app from the list.

Are you sure when you press the button which lets you choose other apps doesn't call `onPause()` until you choose an app ? I doubt that.

Comment: It calls onPause right before showing the list of apps.

Comment: yes i know that.. Thats what Im saying, the OP said that onPause() is called after selecting an app..

Answer (score 0):

The application will call the onPause method initially right before the list of apps appears, but not when it is swiped away (or even when another app is selected)

Answer (score 0):

Yes onPause() is always called before onDestroy(). It goes like this: onPaused() --> onStop() --> onDestroy()

[image]

Always follow the direction of the arrows. Those methods go in a consecutive manner no matter what. A method like onStop() is always executed after onPause() and before onDestroy() no matter the situation.

Comment: `onPause()` is the only one you can guarantee will be called. `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` may not be.

Comment: I thought he meant he swiped away the app itself... not other apps

Comment: "But here is the question. When I open app list where I can switch between apps and I will swipe the app away to close it, will onPause() be called? I know that onDestroy() is always called in that case but is onPause() always called before onDestroy() in that case?" - By what he means here I am completely right. He means that he swipes the app itself away.

Comment: `onPause()` will be called. If you swipe away the app, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` actually may not be called. Note the cutoff line that goes left from `onPause()`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/images/training/basics/basic-lifecycle-paused.png. Have a look at this other one. The cutoff line is not there. In all my experience I have never had apps not go through onStop() and onDestroy(). If you could let me know of a case when that happens that would be great

Comment: That's great and all, but if you go to the Activity page I linked in my answer, it explains it. Basically, pre-Honeycomb, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` may not be called before an app is killed. From Honeycomb and onward, an app is not labeled as `killable` until `onStop()` has been called and completed.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense now. So killing of the app in onPause() is not guaranteed anymore after Honeycomb. The methods following it might not execute. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The activity lifecycle is **always** called in the order given in the documentation. Meaning `onCreate` > `onStart` > `onResume` > `onPause` > `onStop` > `onDestroy`. There can be some repeats of calls, such as going back and forth between `onResume` and `onPause` as the activity comes to the foreground and moves to the background, but they are always in this order. Meaning, if you're certain `onDestroy` is being called, then you can be certain `onPause` and `onStop` have been called.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the OP is correct. I was shocked as well.
Forever, showing the Recent Apps would trigger the pause.
Recent changes of Android 11 don't pause until the other app is selected.
This means that on Android 11 apps visible on Recent Apps are live, not thumbnails.

If you were to show a privacy screen on pause, and dismiss on resume, you will see the privacy on the thumbnail on older OS but 11 you will see the privacy flash onto the thumb as it animates away once the other app is selected.

Comment: Which device did you test this on? Are you sure you were on Android 11 and not 12?